# How to remove an string object from a list?

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have  2 list of String  `Header1` and `Header2`

```
List<String> Header1 = new List<String>();
Header1.add("String1");
Header1.add("String2");
Header1.add("String3");
Header1.add("String4");
```

and

```
    List<String> Header2 = new List<String>();
    Header2.add("STRING1");
    Header2.add("STRING2");
```

I would like to remove these entries "String1" and "String2" in `Header2` from `Header1` by ignoring the case sensitivity.

Any idea how to do it either using `LINQ` or string operation as well.

Thanks

Comment: you want to remove strings from Header1 that are present in Header2?

Comment: @Usman, Yes that's right.

Answer (score 7):

```
Header1.RemoveAll(x => 
            Header2.Contains(x, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Answer (score 6):

There's no need for Linq. The `List` class has a convenient [`RemoveAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx) method you can use:

```
var stringsToRemove = new[] { "string1", "string2" };
var comp = StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase;
Header1.RemoveAll(s => Header2.Any(t => s.Equals(t, comp)));
```

Comment: Thanks, But I would like to use the List `Header2`. I donot know the list count in Header2

Comment: @www.sapnaedu.in Sorry, I miss-read the question at first. See my updated answer

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
Header1.Except(Header2, new EqualityComparer<string>((a, b) => a.Equals(b, StringComparison,OrdinalIgnoreCase)));
```

The `EqualityComparer` lets you specify a custom comparer so that it will only returns true when the `string`s are equal without considering the case.

[MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think LINQ allows you to modify collections. However, if you're happy to produce a new collection without the items from Header2, try something like this:

```
var result = Header1.Except(Header2, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

If you do want to modify the original list, try something like this:

```
Header1.RemoveAll(item => Header2.Contains(item, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```